# Looking for a particular Gintama episode number

Tags: gintama

I watched this series ages ago and I can't seem to be able to find the episode where Hattori and Gin are hospitalized.

Comment: Perhaps go through the episode lists on Wikipedia? If you have some keywords, you might be able to do a quick check with the "find" function.

Comment: Tried, that, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is [**Episode 67**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1bor42rkjo) (Season 2).

[**This**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Lto6aV70A) is a clip from the episode.

Comment: Yes! This is the one, I was looking more for the candle + Zenzou clip though :P